# openshift - php error 404 when accessing image asset

Tags: php, openshift, processwire

Installed the PHP cartridge and processwire over that cartridge.

Made some changes to the stylesheet. This sheet needs files in the folder site/templates/imgs/.  (backgrounds and others).

Unfortunately, I'm unable to see these images in my site because there's a 404 error whenever I try to load them.

I've tried several changes to the file app-root/runtime/repo/php/.htaccess, but without success.

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: you could post your solution as answer and mark this answer as solving ;-)

Comment: Thank U. It's done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I had a mistake in my stylesheet, referencing the image as "/naeg/site/templates/imgs...", instead of "/site/templates/imgs...". In my development environment, I had the app in the context "/naeg". I'll leave this here, hoping will be useful for anyone.